# How to download a file from VPS using Github Actions and save it as artifact?

Tags: github-actions

I am connecting to my VPS using `appleboy/ssh-action` and generating a .SQL backup file of my postgres database (running in docker).

Now, I want to download this generated file and upload it as an artifact. I know that I can use `actions/upload-artifact` to actually upload the artifact, but how can I download it first to be able to use this step?

Or if this isn't the correct way to actually do it, how should I generate the file, and upload it as an artifact?

Current step:

```yaml
jobs:
  backup-db:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump database
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        env:
          POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ env.POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME }}
          POSTGRES_MAIN_USER: ${{ env.POSTGRES_MAIN_USER }}
          POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_NAME: ${{ env.POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_NAME }}
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.VPS_HOST }}
          port: ${{ secrets.VPS_PORT }}
          username: ${{ secrets.VPS_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.VPS_KEY }}
          envs: POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME,POSTGRES_MAIN_USER,POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_NAME
          script: |
            docker exec ${POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME} pg_dump -U ${POSTGRES_MAIN_USER} ${POSTGRES_MAIN_DB_NAME} > postgres_backup/backup_$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').sql
```

Possible next step, once the file is downloaded from VPS:

```yaml
      - name: Archive database dump
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: latest-dump.sql.bz2
          path: latest-dump.sql.bz2
          if-no-files-found: error
          retention-days: 14
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action. However, looks like you can also run `ssh` directly and get output too.

Comment: Looks like scp-action is only to upload to VPS instead of from VPS. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: You can use `scp` command from the runner in the next step after generating the file.

Comment: I tried that, but got "err: Host key verification failed.". Not sure exactly why, but couldn't make it work. A lot of threads with this error, but for now no working solution.